# Sort an array based on order of another array

Tags: php, sorting

I have two arrays:

```
$arr_a = ['A', 'F', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'B'];
$arr_b = ['D', 'A', 'F'];
```

, and I need an array with values of $arr_b that is sorted by $arr_a, like this:

```
array(3) {[0]=>string(1) "A", [1]=>string(1) "F", [2]=>string(1) "D"}
```

What would be the best way to do it?

PS. All the entries in $arr_b are present in $arr_a, and there is no double entries in $arr_b, and the keys in resultin array are irrelevant, really.

Comment: Have you tried any ways so far? You can iterate over $arr_a, checking against $arr_b, and creating a newly formatted $arr_c- but I'm sure theres a better way to do this with a sort function, so I'll leave this in the comments.

Comment: What if `$arr_b` contains more items or items that are not in `$arr_a`?

Comment: Will there ever be values in b, that are not in a?

Comment: All the values of $arr_b are always in $arr_a, no need to take that in account. Also the keys in resulting array are irrelevant, really. And $arr_b is done with array_unique, so no double entries.
I've tried iterating the array, making new one and then multisorting, but there must be a reasonable way, too? :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably not a job for sorting.  `array_intersect()` will return items in `$arr_a` that are in `$arr_b` in the order that they are in `$arr_a`:

```
$arr_b = array_intersect($arr_a, $arr_b);
```

If you need to re-index then just use `array_values()` afterward.

Comment: Damn. Blew my answer out of the water :D +1

Comment: Damn me too :) Simple and whatnot else. No reason not to accept it as an answer. Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

This is what I think you want but your question is not too clear.

```
$result = array_filter($arr_a, function($item) use($arr_b){
    return in_array($item, $arr_b);
});
```

Which results in

```
array(3) {
    [0] = string(1) "A"
    [1] = string(1) "F"
    [3] = string(1) "D"
}
```

Comment: does the job exactly how it should, thank you very much. Still Abracadever's seems shorter and a little cleverer.